# Mismatching properties in array of objects

Tags: javascript

I have a list of names (first + last). I want to mismatch all the fullname and lastname such that no full name is common between new list and initital list of names.

```
Mike,Pence
Tom,ho
Dave, hike
.......so on  ...
```

valid output would be:

```
Mike,hike
Tom,pence
Dave,ho
.......so on  ...
```

My data is

```
      var name = [ {
       firstN: 'Mike',
       lastN: 'Pence',
       fullName: 'Mike Pence'
    },
    { 
       firstN: 'Tom',
       lastN: 'Ho',
       fullName: 'Tom Ho'
    },
    { 
       firstN: 'Dave',
       lastN: 'hike',
       fullName: 'Dave Hike
    }
```

................and so on upto 100s
 ]

**Expected Output:**

```
 New List  = [ {
       firstN: 'Mike',
       lastN: 'Hike',
       fullName: 'Mike Hike'
    },
    { 
       firstN: 'Tom',
       lastN: 'Pence',
       fullName: 'Tom Pence'
    },
    { 
       firstN: 'Dave',
       lastN: 'ho',
       fullName: 'Dave Ho
    }
```

Comment: Your question is itself a puzzle! :)

Comment: So you need to mismatch all the first name and last name. No full name should be correct right?

Comment: Write down the rules for modifying the list in English (they are not clear from your question). Then, implement those rules in JavaScript.

Comment: @torazaburo : edited the question

Comment: @GauravChaudhary : edited the question

Comment: *"no first or last name may be used more than once."* - Does that mean that the initial list doesn't have any repeated first or last names? (At least, not in the first ten items, which according to your point 1 is all you can use...)

Comment: no first or last name may be used more than once in modified list. Yes my initial list wont have repeated names

Comment: I get unique names like this so I dont have to deal with repetition http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43381945/searching-for-unique-properties-in-the-array-object

Comment: I still don't understand the process by which you are creating your desired output. Once you've described that, it should be pretty easy to write a little program to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You clarified in a comment that your initial list will not have any repeated first or last names, so all you need to do is "slide" each person's surname up to pair with the previous person's first name:

```js
var input = [{"firstN":"Andrew","lastN":"Anderson","fullName":"Andrew Anderson"},{"firstN":"Belinda","lastN":"Brown","fullName":"Belinda Brown"},{"firstN":"Clare","lastN":"Charleston","fullName":"Clare Charleston"},{"firstN":"David","lastN":"Downer","fullName":"David Downer"},{"firstN":"Edwin","lastN":"Edwards","fullName":"Edwin Edwards"},{"firstN":"Francine","lastN":"Fellows","fullName":"Francine Fellows"},{"firstN":"Gary","lastN":"Green","fullName":"Gary Green"},{"firstN":"Harriot","lastN":"Harcourt","fullName":"Harriot Harcourt"},{"firstN":"Irwin","lastN":"Inglesson","fullName":"Irwin Inglesson"},{"firstN":"Jennifer","lastN":"Jones","fullName":"Jennifer Jones"}]

var output = input.map(function(p, i, a) {
  var next = (i + 1) % a.length
  return {
    firstN: p.firstN,
    lastN: a[next].lastN,
    fullName: p.firstN + ' ' + a[next].lastN
  }
})

console.log(output)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this. Just need to change the logic in shuffling array since sometimes it produces same value at the same index.

```js
var nameList =[{firstN:'Tom',lastN:'Ho',fullName:'Tom Ho'},{firstN:'Mike',lastN:'Pence',fullName:'Mike Pence'},{firstN:'Dave',lastN:'Hike',fullName:'Dave Hike'}]

var newNameList = [];

var length = nameList.length;
for (var a=[],i=0;i<length;++i) a[i]=i;

function shuffle(array) {
  var tmp, current, top = array.length;
  if(top) while(--top) {
    current = Math.floor(Math.random() * (top + 1));
    tmp = array[current];
    array[current] = array[top];
    array[top] = tmp;
  }
  return array;
}
a = shuffle(a);

for(var i=0;i<length;i++){
  newNameList[i] = {};
  newNameList[i].firstN = nameList[i].firstN;
  newNameList[i].lastN = nameList[a[i]].lastN;
  newNameList[i].fullName = newNameList[i].firstN + " "+       newNameList[i].lastN;
}

console.log(newNameList)
```